# Setting the x axis as time (years, months) for a set of values

Tags: python, numpy, time, graph, plot

I have a set of values which correspond to a month and a year (January 2012, March 2012, October 2012 through to 2014), and im trying to plot the values for each month, however when I run the script the x axis is assigned as '1, 2, 3' etc

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([10, 180, 153, 80, 11, 92, 201, 74, 24])
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.title('Number over time')
plt.show()
plt.ylim([0,300])
plt.show()
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/sqjWR0J.png]

How can I set the X axis to be these specific months or all the months from 2011-2014?

I found the demo plots from matplotlib to be extremely confusing http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually send mpl any dates. It doesn't know you're trying to plot dates on the x axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

dates = []
for year in range(2012, 2014):
    for month in range(1, 12):
        dates.append(dt.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=1))

y = [10, 180, 153, 80, 11, 92, 201, 74, 24]
plt.plot(dates[:9], y)
plt.show()
```

This example plots only the first 9 months since that's the length of your example list you're plotting. If you want specific dates, just declare them yourself via the `datetime` module. I.e. your date[0] looks like:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0) 
                 #year, month, day, hour min if I recall correctly.
```